# Is it possible to get percentile on aggregated data in Influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to get percentile on aggregated data in Influxdb?

Say, my data is

> db,label1=value1 measure1_count=20 measure1_mean=0.8 140000000000
>
> db,label1=value1 measure1_count=8 measure1_mean=0.9 140000001000
>
> db,label1=value1 measure1_count=15 measure1_mean=0.4 140000002000

It it possible to do percentile on above data in influxdb1/2?

Answer (score 0):

Influx db provide the Median aggregate function for calculating median.

```
select  MEDIAN(Value) from ProcessData group by TagName
```

[image]
**Note:** MEDIAN() is nearly equivalent to PERCENTILE(field_key, 50), except MEDIAN() returns the average of the two middle field values if the field contains an even number of values.

[https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#:~:text=Note%3A%20MEDIAN()%20is%20nearly,an%20even%20number%20of%20values](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20MEDIAN()%20is%20nearly,an%20even%20number%20of%20values).

Comment: But what if I need 95th, 90th, etc.